# Add a Submit button to list forms for SharePoint 2019 on-prem

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, 2019, powerapp

How can we customize the Default list form for SharePoint 2019?

I need to add a Save and Submit button and the status should be Draft/Submitted based on the button clicked

How can this be achieved?

If I edit the newitem.aspx and add a content editor webpart and create custom javascript/html based form, will it work even with the modern view?

Answer (score 1):

Content editor web part won't work with Modern view...Customizing the default list form with what you need is only possible with a classic view where you can add javascript/HTML.

For the modern view - this kind of customization is not possible, you will have to build a form using SPFx web part to achieve this.

Another alternate way would be to have the status column choose by the user and let the OOTB form do its work :)

Comment: Yeah Siddharth, I was thinking to have a yes/no field :)  just trying to explore if there are any other options
PowerApps doesn't seem to be an easy option for on-prem

Comment: looks like we can change the default form for New/Edit in SharePoint designer and that works for modern view as well.

Answer (score 0):

No, the custom javascript/html based form only works for classic view. It would not work in modern view.

The best way is using powerapps to custom the modern form: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/gateway-management